# Performing just SELECT commands on SQLite

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, select, system.data.sqlite

I have made a SQLite database (~700MB, 3 tables, 3 indexes - 1 rtree index and 2 primary keys). I have marked it as a read-only file (on Windows).

Is it safe and performant to execute just SELECT commands on this database from multiple threads?

If so how can it be made more performant (any options or flags to enable, any tiny tunings)?

This application is in C# using System.Data.SQLite (1.0.82.0), compiled for .NET 4.0 on a x64 machine. And It works fine (not necessarily performant or correctly paralleled because I can not/do not know (how to) prove them). Currently I have no real bottleneck but soon I will! I need to search the rtree as fast as possible. (On my machine 4GB, 2 Cores) It takes sometimes more than 5 milliseconds to search the rtree. I have made that part multithreaded to process my data paralleled. And according to structure of the [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) (or I think R*-Tree in SQLite's case) if my database grows to some GB it should be no problem because these trees has low depths and are fast on large datasets. But if any improvements are possible, then it should be considered in this application.

I can not be sure that the part that has been made parallel is really running in parallel and for example SQLite (or System.Data.SQLite) has not an internal lock. In fact in some tests the parallel version runs slower!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be safe, provided each thread has its own connection or you use locks to prevent multiple threads from using the same connection at the same time.

Comment: The "*..provided..*" is very important to heed.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it safe and performant to execute just SELECT commands on this database from multiple threads?

Most likely

> how can it be made more performant (if it is possible)?

What are your bottlenecks?  Disk I/O?  Processor?  Memory?

Making an application more performant is best done by 1) identifying the pieces that are performing poorly (and can be improved) and 2) making those pieces more performant.  There are a multitude of tools out there that will identify the slowest parts of your code so you know what to tackle first.  It makes no sense to shave 10ms off of a query when the program takes the results of that query and spends 10 seconds writing it to disk.

There's not a "magic wand" that you can wave over an application (especially a database-driven application) and make it run faster.  You need to know *what to fix* first.

Comment: I have added some more description. Thaks

Answer (score 1):

You can set the threading support level:  http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

> SQLite support three different threading modes:
>
> **Single-thread**. In this mode, all mutexes are disabled and SQLite is unsafe to use in more than a single thread at once.
>
> **Multi-thread**. In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads provided that no single database connection is used simultaneously in two or more threads.
>
> **Serialized**. In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads with no restriction.
>
> The threading mode can be selected at compile-time (when the SQLite library is being compiled from source code) or at start-time (when the application that intends to use SQLite is initializing) or at run-time (when a new SQLite database connection is being created). Generally speaking, run-time overrides start-time and start-time overrides compile-time. Except, single-thread mode cannot be overridden once selected.
>
> **The default mode is serialized.**

The slowdown you are seeing is the serialization of requests. Change the threading model and things will speed up. Keep in mind "unsafe" probably means both readers and writers at the same time. I am not sure what is the best mode for ONLY readers.

Comment: I have only used Multi-thread because I thought (from it's description) it is what I should choose. I have tested other options too. The problem is I am not sure if for example with Single-thread option a connection be made, it would work correctly in a multi threaded application. How can I test if it is returning the correct answer? (Other that porting my database to another database and test results with that another database ;) because my tests actually use the SQLite itself).

Comment: You could always test against the serialized mode which is thread safe

Comment: Sometimes in these situations I try and find a unit test in the sqlite source to check against. Make sure to eliminate anything else your app is doing. The sqlite source is open so you can tack in another unit test to validate your results